# Low validation accuracy but the train have high accuracy, also the validation loss so high

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, training-data

i have a question, when im creating the model, why it have high accuracy and low loss, but the validation accuracy low and validation loss so high.
Any recommend way to improve this?
It took 256 samples, validate on 65 samples.
This is the code that i used to

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
# from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Sequential
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
# from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam,RMSprop,SGD
from keras.optimizers import Adam , RMSprop, SGD
import pickle 
from streamlit_webrtc import webrtc_streamer


################################################################
path = 'DatasetsBatik'
testRatio = 0.2
validationRatio = 0.2
imageDimension =(32,32,3)
batchSizeVal=2
epochsVal=200
stepsPerEpochVal=200


################################################################
images=[]
classNumber =[]

myList = os.listdir(path)
print("Total Number of Classes Detected" , " : " ,  len(myList))
NumberOfClasses =len(myList)

print("Importing Classes ....")
for x in range(0,NumberOfClasses):
#0 Representing Kawung,
#1 Representing Megamendung,
#2 Representing Parang,
#3 Representing Sekar Jagad,
#4 Representing Simbut,

    myPicList = os.listdir(path+"/"+str(x))

    for y in myPicList:
        currentImage = cv2.imread(path+"/"+str(x)+"/"+y)
        currentImage = cv2.resize(currentImage, (imageDimension[0],imageDimension[1]) )
        images.append(currentImage)
        classNumber.append(x)
    print(x,end = " " )  
print("")
print(len(classNumber))

images = np.array(images)
classNumber = np.array(classNumber)

# print(images.shape)
# print(classNumber.shape)

### Split Data
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(images,classNumber,test_size = testRatio)
X_train,X_validation,Y_train,Y_validation= train_test_split(X_train,Y_train,test_size = validationRatio)


print("x_train.shape = " + str(X_train.shape))
print("x_test.shape = " +str(X_test.shape))
print("x_validation.shape = "+str(X_validation.shape))


NumberOfSamples=[]
for x in range(0,NumberOfClasses):
    # print(len(np.where(Y_train ==x)[0]))
    NumberOfSamples.append(len(np.where(Y_train==x)[0]))
print("Number Of Samples : " +str(NumberOfSamples))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.bar(range(0,NumberOfClasses),NumberOfSamples)
plt.title("Number of Images for each Class")
plt.xlabel("Class ID")
plt.ylabel("Number of Images")
plt.show()

# print(X_train)


def PreProcessing(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img/255 
    return img

# img = X_train[30]
# img = cv2.resize(img,(300,300))
# cv2.imshow("PreProcessed",img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

X_train=np.array(list(map(PreProcessing,X_train)))
# print(X_train)
X_test=np.array(list(map(PreProcessing,X_test)))
X_validation=np.array(list(map(PreProcessing,X_validation)))

# print(X_train.shape)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],X_test.shape[2],1)
X_validation = X_validation.reshape(X_validation.shape[0],X_validation.shape[1],X_validation.shape[2],1)

# print(X_train.shape)

dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1,zoom_range=0.2,shear_range=0.1,rotation_range=10)
dataGen.fit(X_train)

Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train,NumberOfClasses) 
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test,NumberOfClasses) 
Y_validation = to_categorical(Y_validation,NumberOfClasses) 

def myModel():
    NumberOfFilters1 = 128  
    NumberOfFilters2 = 256
    sizeOfFilter1=(5,5)
    sizeOfFilter2=(3,3)
    sizeOfPool=(2,2)
    
    NumberOfNode=128
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add((Conv2D(NumberOfFilters1,sizeOfFilter1,input_shape=(imageDimension[0],imageDimension[1],1),activation='relu')))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=sizeOfPool))
    
    # model.add((Conv2D(NumberOfFilters1,sizeOfFilter1,activation='relu')))
    # model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=sizeOfPool))
    # model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    model.add((Conv2D(NumberOfFilters2,sizeOfFilter2,activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=sizeOfPool))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    # model.add((Conv2D(NumberOfFilters2,sizeOfFilter2,activation='relu')))
    # model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=sizeOfPool))
    # model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(NumberOfNode,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(NumberOfClasses,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0005),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = myModel()
print(model.summary())




history = model.fit_generator(dataGen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=batchSizeVal),steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpochVal,epochs=epochsVal,validation_data=(X_validation,Y_validation),shuffle=1)
# history= model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batchSizeVal,epochs=epochsVal,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation))

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.legend(['training','validation'])
plt.title('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.legend(['training','validation'])
plt.title('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()

score= model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test,verbose=0)
print('Test Score =',score[0])
print('Score Accuracy  = ',score[1])

print(score)
# print(model.metrics_names)

pickle_out=open("10_TestModel4","wb")
pickle.dump(model,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

This is the result that i have now
[Epoch 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltg7w.png)

[Finish,Epoch 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzmPo.png)

I have tried to remove or add hidden layer, and also try some different learning rate, epoch, batch size, steps per epoch, adding drop out for the layer . Any recommend would be very helpfull, thankyou.

Comment: augment your input data and try to provide more data if possible.

Comment: ahh okay, how much data should I add? now im having arround 402 data and 5 label. 
in each label almost have arround 60-100 each

Comment: that should be good enough to start with, augment your training data. if you can augment in data generator it'll be even better.

Comment: It seems your model is overfitting, you can try strategies to prevent overfitting mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#strategies_to_prevent_overfitting). Add dropout layers only after dense layers, not with conv layers and try by providing the default `learning_rate` for Adam optimizer. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.